# Event Sourcing Refactoring

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I've been studying DDD for a while, and stumbled into design patterns like CQRS, and Event sourcing (ES). These patterns can be used to help achieving some concepts of DDD with less effort. 
In the architecture exemplified below, the aggregates know how to handle the commands and events related to itself. In other words, the Event Handlers and Command Handlers are the Aggregates.

Then, I’ve started modeling one sample Domain just to understand how the implementation would follow the business logic. For this question here is my domain (It’s based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx)):

[image: Example Domain]

I know this is a bad modeled example, but I’m using it just as an example. 
So, using ES, at the end of the operation, we would save all the events (Green arrows) into the event store (if there were no Exceptions), each event into its given Event Stream (Aggregate Type + Aggregate Id):

[image: Event Streams]

Everything seems right until now. So If we want to Rebuild the internal state of an instance of any of this Aggregate, we only have to new it up (new()) and apply all the events saved in its respective Event Stream in the correct order.

[image: Event Rebuild]

My question is related to changes in the model. Because, software development is a process where we never stop learning about our domain, and we always come with new ideas. So, let’s analyze some change scenarios:

## Change Scenario 1:

Let´s pretend that now, if the ***Reservation Aggregate*** check’s that the seat is not available, it should send an event (***Seat not reserved***) and this event should be handled by one new Aggregate that will store all people that got their seat not reserved:

[image: First Change]

In the hypothesis where the old system already handled the initial command (***Place order***) correctly, and saved all the events to its respective event streams:

- When we want to Rebuild the internal state of an instance of any of this Aggregate, we only have to new it up (new()) and apply all the events saved in its respective Event Stream in the correct order. (Nothing changed). The only thing, is that the new Use case didn’t exist back in the old model.

## Change Scenario 2:

Let’s pretend that now, when the payment is accepted we handle this event (***Payment Accepted***) in a new Aggregate (***Finance Aggregate***) and not in the ***Order Aggregate*** anymore. And It send a new Event (***Payment Received***) to the ***Order Aggregate***. I know this scenario is not well structured, but something like this could happen.

[image: Second Change]

In the hypothesis where the old system already handled the initial command (***Place order***) correctly, and saved all the events to its respective event streams:

- When we want to Rebuild the internal state of an instance of any of this Aggregate, we have a problem when applying the events from the Aggregate Event Stream to itself:

[image: Error Rebuilding]

Now, the order doesn’t know anymore how to handle ***Payment Accepted*** Event.

## Problems

So as the examples showed, whenever a system change reflects in an event being handled by a different event handler (Aggregate), there are some major problems. Because, we cannot rebuild the internal state anymore.
So, this problem can have some solutions:

## Possible Solution

When an event is not handled by the aggregate in which Event Stream it is stored, we can find the new handler and create a new instance and send the event to it. But to maintain the internal state correct, we need the last event (***Payment Received***) to be handled by the ***Order Aggregate***. So, we let it dispatch the event (and possible commands):

[image: Solution Rebuild]

This solution can have some problems. Let’s imagine that a new command (***Place Order***) arrives and it has to create this order instance and save the new state. Now we would have:

[image: New Streams]

In gray are the events that were already saved in the last call when the system hadn’t already gone through model changes.
We can see that a new Event Stream is created for the new aggregate (***Finance W***). And we can see that Event Streams are append-only, so the ***Payment Accepted*** event in the ***Order Y*** Event Stream is still there.
The first ***Payment Accepted*** event in ***Finance W*** Event Stream is the one that was supposed to be handled by the ***Order*** but had to find a new handler.
The Yellow payment received event in ***Order’s*** Event Stream is the event that was generated by the new handler of the ***Payment Accepted*** when the ***Payment Accepted*** event from the ***Order’s*** Event Stream was handled by the ***Finance***.
All the other Green Events are new events that were generated by handling the ***Place Order*** Command in the new model.

## Problem With the Solution

The next time the aggregate needs to be rebuild, there will be a Payment Accepted event in the stream (because it is append-only), and it will again call the new handler, but this have already been done and the Payment Received event have already been saved to the stream. So, it is not necessary to go through this again, we could ignore this event and continue.

## Question

So, my question is how can we handle with model changes that impact who handle each event? How can we rebuild the internal state of an Aggregate after a change like this?
Will we need to build some event Stream migration that changes the events from one stream to the new schema (one or more streams)? Just like we would need in a Relational database?
Will we never be allowed to remove one handler, so we can only add new handlers? This would lead to unmanageable system…

Comment: Greg Young has a book that touches on that (see "stream boundaries are wrong") - https://leanpub.com/esversioning

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs
If you ask this question on the google group for CQRS, you are going to get a much richer answer than you will here.

Answer (score 6):

You got almost all right, except one thing: **Aggregates should not handle events from other Aggregates**. It's like a non-event-sourced Aggregate shares a table with another Aggregate: they should not.

In event-driven DDD, Aggregates are the system's building blocks that receive Commands (things that express the intent) and return Events (things that had happened). For every Command type must exist *one and only one* Aggregate type that handle it. Before executing a Command, the Aggregate is fed with all *its own* previously emitted Events, that is, every Event that was emitted in the past by *this* Aggregate instance is applied to *this* Aggregate instance, in the chronological order.

So, if you want to correctly model your system, you are not allowed to send events from one Aggregate as events to another Aggregate (a different type or instance).

If you need to model business processes that involve multiple Aggregates, the correct way of doing it is by using a **Saga/Process manager**. This is a different component. It is the opposite of an Aggregate.
It receive Events emitted by Aggregates and sends Commands to other Aggregates.

In simplest cases, a Saga manager simply takes properties from one Event and creates+populates a Command with those properties. Then it sends the Command to the destination Aggregate.

In more complicated cases, the Saga waits for multiple Events and when all are received only then it creates and sends a Command.

The Saga may also deduplicate or reorder events.

In your case, a Saga could be `Sale`, whose purpose would be to *coordinate* the entire sales process, from ordering to product dispatching.

**In conclusion**, you have that problem because you have not modeled correctly your system. If your Aggregates would have handled only their specific Commands (and not somebody else's Events) then even if you must create a new Saga when a new Business process emerges, it would send the same Command to the Same Aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

Answering briefly

> my question is how can we handle with model changes that impact who handle each event?

Handling events is generally an easy thing to change, because the handling part is ephemeral.  Events have a single writer, but they can have many readers.  You just need to arrange for the plumbing to notify each subscriber of the event.

So in scenario #1, its the PaymentAggregate that writes down the PaymentAccepted event (in its own stream), and then your plumbing notifies the OrderAggregate that the PaymentAccepted event happened, and it does the next thing in its own logic.

To change to scenario #2, we'd leave the Payment Aggregate unchanged, but we'd arrange the plumbing so that it tells the FinanceAggregate about PaymentAccepted, and that it tells the OrderAggregate about PaymentReceived.

Your pictures make it hard to see this; I think you aren't being careful to track that each change of state is stored in the stream of the aggregate that changed.  Not your fault - the Microsoft picture is really awful.

In other words, your arrow #3 "Seats Reserved" isn't a `SeatsReserved` event, it's a `Handle(SeatsReserved)` *command*.